# Counter assignments

Tags: notebooks, stylesheet, cells

I'm  trying to create a specific outline format to match some course materials I am required to submit in a particular way.

I know how to create auto-numbered cells using `Automatic` numbering.

The structure I am looking for is something like

- Section 1

  - Subsection 1
  - Subsection 2
  - Subsection 3
- Section 2

  - Subsection 4
  - Subsection 5
- Section 3

  - Subsection 6

etc.

I know these is a way to NOT have the `Subsection` cells go back to one at each `Section` heading,  but I can't find the way to make that happen.  I'd like to be able to move the `Section` cells if necessary but have the `Subsection` cells number from $1$ - whatever and not reset in each section.

Is this possible?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate: [Can I make the subsection CounterBox continue counting across section boundaries?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28925)