# Setting a Counter in Mathematica Notebook

Tags: notebooks

I would like to write a book using *Mathematica*, but I will write one chapter on several files. How to tell *Mathematica* that the `BookChapterNumber` pointer has the value pointing to the next file in the same chapter ?

Comment: Hi wono. Is [this QandA](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25992/different-chapters-in-different-files) any use?

Comment: Yes you are right. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8):

I wrote a book with Mathematica 10 years ago. The way I set it up was to create a counter called "Chapter" but you could also use "Title". In your title style you need to ensure all counters are reset. Also in the section style you will want to reset the subsection counter etc.

```
Cell[StyleData["Title"],
...
 CounterAssignments->{{"Section", 0}, {"Subsection", 0}, {"Subsubsection", 0}, {"FigureCaption", 0}, {"Table", 0}, {"BulletedList", 0}, {"EquationNumbered", 0} etc etc},
...]
```

To number equations you need to include the chapter counter:

```
Cell[StyleData["EquationNumbered"],
...
 CellFrameLabels->{{None, 
    Cell[
     TextData[{"(", 
       CounterBox["Chapter"], ".", 
       CounterBox["EquationNumbered"], ")   "}]]}, {None, None}},
...]
```

In each chapter notebook include the chapter counter in the title cell:

```
Cell["Your Title for Chapter 3", "Title",
 CounterAssignments->{{"Chapter", 3}}]
```

And add the chapter counter to your sections:

```
Cell[TextData[{
 CounterBox["Chapter"],".",CounterBox["Section"],
 "\tSection Title"
}], "Section"]

Cell[BoxData[
 FormBox[Cell["x+1"], TraditionalForm]], "EquationNumbered"]
```

[image]