# Master Document

Tags: notebooks

I'm wandering is there Master document concept in Mathematica so that the counter will be counted sequencially in master document. Mean file in child document, the counter follow from master document.
I knew that I can setup the counter in the specific file, but then if I add some new section in the first file, then I should change the start counter in the next file. I don't want it, I like next file change the start counter directly, just like Latex

Comment: AFAIK not automatically but easy to set up manually as per my answer to another question the other day http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32691/setting-a-counter-in-mathematica-notebook/32752#32752

Comment: @Mike That question was asked by the same user.  Apparently he either didn't understand it or wants something different.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard didn't notice it was the same person. Can't think of anything to add to previous answer without additional info on what they want ...but this is probably a dupe of the previous Q asked

Comment: @Mike Perhaps then you should vote to close? :-)